# Generate random numbers without repetition in C

Tags: c

The below result can generate random numbers but repetition of numbers still occurs. Guess there's smtg wrong  within the *if else* statement?

ADDITIONAL:
The question is:
**Generate the entries as random numbers and repeatedly make new numbers until a legal entry value is found.**
Hence, swapping of elements is not the solution for this.

```
int x = 0, y = 0, input[20], current, temp;

main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (x = 0; x < 20;x++){
        input[x] = rand() % 20 + 1;

        for (y = 0; y < 20; y++){
            if (input[x] == input[y]){
                if (y != x){
                    input[x] = rand() % 20 + 1;
                    y = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    for (x = 0; x < 20; x++){
        printf("Input[%d]: %d\n", x + 1, input[x]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Your input array is one too small, to start with.

Comment: Random numbers without repetition are just a random *permutation*.

Comment: Your `for` loops are overflowing.  Your `input` array has 19 elements. And `int main(void)` please.

Comment: ^^^ or your loops are one too long.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I was thinking about shuffling the numbers, but question rejected that. "Generate the entries as random numbers and repeatedly make new numbers until a legal entry value is found."

Comment: Umm.. what question?

Comment: thanks for that, i'd modified the array size @MartinJames

Comment: thanks for that, i'd modified the array size @Ouss4

Comment: Your `input[y]` may access uninitialized part of `input` array (always when `y>x`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from some obvious problems (see the comments...)

When you find a duplicate you generate a new number, but you don't restart the check for duplicates, so it won't compare it with previous values in the array.

Comment: Yes, the logic is all messed up.  There is no need to check for dups for the first entry, and no need for any dup-checker loop to index further than the current insert index less1.

Comment: I have modified my code, which added a y = 0; inside the nested IF statement, but sometimes it still gave me repetition, very less chance of getting fully randomized without repetition

Comment: @JeosiyyChu: in that case after y++, you start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean array and use direct hashing.
Let's say r is the first random number.
make `input[r]=1;`Now, when the next random number is generated you can simply check if it has been previously generated using

```
if(!input[r])
{
...
}
```

Now each time the condition is false, decrement the loop counter by 1.

```
  for (x = 0; x < 20; x++)
  {
    int r=rand()%20+1;
    if(!arr[r])
      printf("%d\n",r);
    else
      x--;
    arr[r]=1;    
  }
```